# Connect to custom bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, client, full-node, mobile

I have a fully synchronized btc node on my network.

Which mobile apps (android) and desktop apps can I use to connect to this node without running a full node/ daemon on the desktop or mobile? And how would I do that?

I really want to just transact through the local node. Every App I have looked at so far runs their own local full node.

The idea is that the family can transact through one local full-node.

Edit: should have read the cli command options on bitcoin-qt

A simple:
bitcoin-qt.exe -connect mynodeIp -addnode mynodeIp

Creates two connections to the node and blocks all others

Comment: If you have set up a bitcoin node, and you want to transact bitcoin on your phone, presumably for smaller amounts, you may want to consider also setting up a lightning node and then have a lighting wallet on your phone. A lightning wallet is considered better for smaller amounts. 

The below is a tutorial on how to do that. (I have no affiliation to particular implementations used in the tutorial, but the technical nuts and bolts are well covered by the author)
https://stopanddecrypt.medium.com/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-installing-a-lightning-node-on-linux-2021-edition-ece227cfc35d

Answer (score 1):

> Which mobile apps (android) and desktop apps can I use to connect to this node without running a full node/ daemon on the desktop or mobile?

Mobile apps:

Good UI/UX for using bitcoin core.
https://github.com/Fonta1n3/FullyNoded (iOS)

It's a simple app to connect to local node for broadcasting transaction. You can add more things if you are a developer.
https://github.com/percy-g2/BitK (Android)

Desktop apps:

https://github.com/cryptoadvance/specter-desktop

https://github.com/bwt-dev/bwt-electrum-plugin (Connect Electrum with bitcoin core full node)

Comment: Thanks - will give these a look :)